# Write "hit_or_stand " function for simple one-player blackjack in python

Tags: python-3.x, blackjack

My question is as what the title suggests: I am not sure if the statement in the `return` clause is correct.

If you can point out where it went wrong or how to correct it, it would be great! Thanks a lot!

[**Description**]
All the common rules of blackjack apply in this case. The decision is based on the result of the last game. In each round, `player` has right to make decision first.

Say I have a function called `hit_or_stand`. Both `player_one_aces` and `player_eleven_aces` are the ace counter parameters for `player`. In specific, `player_one_aces` is the counter when `ace=1` and the number of card that `ace=11` is counted under `player_eleven_aces*`. As long as `player_sum` is not equal to 21, the value of `ace` can be `11`.

```
def hit_or_stand(dealer_sum, player_sum, player_one_aces, player_eleven_aces):

    return  player_sum < dealer_sum and  (player_eleven_aces*11 + player_one_aces*1)<21 if player_sum <= 21 else  (player_eleven_aces*1 + player_one_aces*1)<21
```

[**Test case**] given `hit_or_stand(10, 20, 2, 1)`, this means `player_total=20, player_one_aces=2, player_eleven_aces=1`.

Comment: Your test case `hit_or_stand(20, 19, 2, 1)` implies that `dealer_sum=20`; how is that possible? As long as the player gets to decide about "hit or stand", the dealer is served only one face-up card, i.e. can have a maximum of 11. The second question is what you want to base your decision on? There are tables for hard and soft hands that show what's the ideal decision in every scenario (player / dealer combination).

Comment: @a_guest cheers mate, points taken. I have updated the question description ;)